# Would it be possible to stop escaping angle brackets in email notifications?

Tags: bug, email, subscription

Here's an email I just received for a tag I subscribe to, showing a summary of a new question asked:

```
Creating tree formed XML from flat XML with Xquery

I have some XML in the following format: 

&lt;data&gt; &lt;row&gt; &lt;id&gt;1&lt;/id&gt; &lt;parent_id/&gt; &lt;/row&gt; &lt;row&gt; &lt;id&gt;2&lt;/id&gt; &lt;...

tagged: xml, xquery Sep 7 at 13:46
```

(The link to this question is [Creating tree formed XML from flat XML with Xquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39371668/creating-tree-formed-xml-from-flat-xml-with-xquery).)

The escaped angle brackets make the summary harder to read.  Ideally, the summary would show the text as is:

```
I have some XML in the following format: <data> <row> <id>1</id> <parent_id/> </row>...
```

As a subscriber to XML-related tags, this would be great!

Comment: Thank you for the link!